# How do I take advantage of Python generators when reading in a huge file and parsing by word?

Tags: python, generator

Here is the relevant code I have.  It is using a generator to get the words from the file.  However, the words are first stored into a variable before entering a function.  Is this correct?

Does this take advantage of the generator functionality?

```
def do_something(words):
    new_list = {}
    for word in words:
        // do stuff to each word
        // then add to new_list
    return new_list

def generate_words(input_file):
    for line in input_file:
        for word in line.split(' '):
            // do stuff to word
            yield word

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("in.txt") as input_file:
        words = generate_words(input_file)
        do_something(words)
```

Thank you

Comment: @jamlak I was thinking that since do_something has to wait for the words variable to be "generated", it is slower than adding words to the list in do_something() as they were yielded instead.  Does that make sense?  Am I missing something?

Comment: That's not a list, it's a dictionary. `do_something` doesn't have to wait for the words variable to be generated, it is generating them one at a time during the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make `words = generate_words(input_file)`, you are simply giving it a reference to the newly created generator. When you run `do_something`, that's when the generator is actually iterated through, `words` is just a reference to it. So the answer is yes, you are taking advantage of generators.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine. What is being stored in `words` is a fresh generator prepared to run the code in `generate_words`; the code will only actually run when the `for word in words:` is triggered. If you want to know more, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) has a whole heap of information.

Answer (score -1):

There is no advantage of using generators in given example.
The main purpose is reduce memory usage.

In the code:

```
for line in input_file:
```

`line` already beed read from file and consumed memory. Then `split` operation create new list and memory been consumed one more time.

So all you have to do is iterate through list items.

While usage of generators will lead creating generator object which yield objects from existing list. It is completely useless.

Comment: You seem to disagree with all the other posters.  Can you explain further?

Comment: I disagree. Loading the file line-by-line uses much less memory than loading the entire file into memory (unless the entire file *is* one line).

Comment: The point is that we are reading each `line` one by one... I agree that  `for word in line.split(' '):  yield word` requires a list from `line.split` to be loaded into memory but when dealing with individual lines, this is a **very quick** operation since that list is **tiny**. `yield`ing from that list is not a costly operation, and you can't shun generators for that. Imagine loading every line in the file into memory... and then performing operations on it without generators, that would be very memory inefficient and slow as well for huge files

Comment: thank for comments. I know about that but wanted more discussion